# WPF Clear combobox text value when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox, binding

I want to clear the combobox text value or set it to another string whenever the checkbox is uncheck. Is there any good way to bind them together in xaml ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a snippet of the XAML and C# code for the ComboBox and Checkbox that you could add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. It is solved with bindings:

```xml
<Grid>
   <ComboBox IsEditable="{Binding ElementName=Box, Path=IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
      <ComboBoxItem>Test</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Test2</ComboBoxItem>
   </ComboBox>
   <CheckBox x:Name="Box" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want to change the text, it may be necessary to write a converter:

```cs
Text="{Binding ElementName=Box, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"
```

Take a look at [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data) about how to write a value converter.